# firebase query is returning null, when chaining .where isEqualTo and isGreaterThanOrEqualTo together

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am querying the next 7 days task for individual users. And getting value first then null. When I chain multiple where.

Code:

```
Query query = collectionReference
.where('authorID', isEqualTo: userID)
.where('dueDateTime', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDay)
.where('dueDateTime', isLessThanOrEqualTo: endDay);
```

console output:

```
flutter: [Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task']  
flutter: [Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task']  
flutter: [Instance of 'Task', Instance of 'Task']  
flutter: null
```

If I remove `.where('authorID', isEqualTo: userID)` I am getting my value.
startDay and endDay are both DateTime. I did try with `Timestamp.fromDate(startDay)`. Also didn't work with `isGreaterThanOrEqualTo` or `isLessThanOrEqualTo` individually.
meaning

```
.where('authorID', isEqualTo: userID)
.where('dueDateTime', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDay);
```

or

```
.where('authorID', isEqualTo: userID)
.where('dueDateTime', isLessThanOrEqualTo: endDay);
```

Doesn't work.

Whole code:

```
  Stream<List<Task>> getNextDaysTasks({
    @required String userID,
    @required DateTime startDay,
    @required DateTime endDay,
  }) {
    CollectionReference collectionReference = reference.collection('tasks/');
    Query query = collectionReference
        .where('authorID', isEqualTo: userID)
        .where('dueDateTime', isGreaterThanOrEqualTo: startDay)
        .where('dueDateTime', isLessThanOrEqualTo: endDay);
    final Stream<QuerySnapshot> snapshots = query.snapshots();
    final result = snapshots.map((collectionSnapshot) => collectionSnapshot.docs
        .map((documentSnapshot) => Task.fromMap(documentSnapshot.data()))
        .toList());
    return result;
  }
```

UI code:

```
StreamBuilder<List<Task>>(
                        stream: DatabaseService().getNextDaysTasks(
                          userID: auth.user.uid,
                          startDay: today,
                          endDay: seventhDay,
                        ),
                        builder: (context, snapshot) {
                          final tasks = snapshot.data ?? [];
                          print(snapshot.data);

                          return CatagoryCard(
                            title: 'Next 7 Days',
                            taskCount: '${tasks.length}',
                            screen: Next7Days(),
                          );
                        }),
```

My database:

[image]

Comment: I don't see that any of your code would generate log output.  All you're doing here is building a query without executing it.  Please edit the question to more clearly explain the code that isn't working the way you expect, including how you log the output.

Comment: @DougStevenson I edited do I have to post the UI code too? I just put a StreamBuilder() there

Comment: It's much easier to help troubleshoot if you `print` something that shows the problem, like the number of documents in the response (if you're getting more or fewer results), or a field of the document in the response (if you're getting the wrong results).

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I am getting what I expected but then it's returning null. I have no idea why.